# SQL SELECT DISTINCT doesn't return distinct columns

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a forum where i want the latest topics to be shown side-by-side with the category in which it belongs. However, when someone makes a topic in the same category twice it shows the category twice and the different topics on the right side.

This is somewhat right, but I want it to be only one category showing. I tried SQL `SELECT DISTINCT` for this, but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone tell me if there is something wrong in the syntax or if the problem lies elsewhere?

```
SELECT DISTINCT topics.topic_id, topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_by, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_name, categories.cat_description 
FROM topics JOIN categories ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id 
ORDER BY topics.topic_date DESC LIMIT 3
```

Also, I want to note that the reason for `LIMIT 3` is because this is from the homepage, where only 3 categories are supposed to show. The problem persists on both the homepage and the category page.

Relevant tables (Pictures):

[Categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvy3G.png)

[Topics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEFqf.png)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT topics.topic_subject instead of topics.topic_id

Comment: Which database system do you use? MySql handles `DISTINCT` as `DISTINCT ROW`.  You can use the `GROUP BY` clause to get distinct columns.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone oh, I was not aware of this! Would you mind posting an answer witht the correct syntax to this, so I can look at it and do some research on it?

Comment: Try @MikeAdamenko's SQL command. He did the job for me and could use some rep. points. :) If you are actually using MySql, your question should be tagged properly to be related to "mysql". See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html for the equivalent example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `DISTINCT` in this case.

To show only one category you need to use `GROUP BY` clause to group you topics.

Try following sql

```
SELECT  topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_by, categories.cat_name, categories.cat_description, count(categories.cat_name) 
FROM topics JOIN categories ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id GROUP BY  categories.cat_name
ORDER BY topics.topic_date DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this does the job with only showing one of the categories, so it answers the question. However, it stops showing the latest topic for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your trying **DISTINCT** for **topic_id column** you need to change it to **topic_subject column**

> topic_id column looks like auto_increment primary key so it always DISTINCT .

change like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT topics.topic_subject, topics.topic_id,
topics.topic_by, categories.cat_id, categories.cat_name, 
categories.cat_description 
FROM topics JOIN categories ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id 
GROUP BY  categories.cat_name
ORDER BY topics.topic_date DESC LIMIT 3
```